# Can't launch TopCoder Applet on IcedTea

Tags: java, java-web-start, icedtea-web

I'm trying to launch TopCoder's Applet using the following command

> **javaws** ContestAppletProd7.2.jnlp

However, I get the following StackTrace:

```
  net.sourceforge.jnlp.LaunchException: Fatal: Launch Error: Could not launch JNLP file. The application has not been initialized, for more information execute javaws/browser from the command line and send a bug report.
    at net.sourceforge.jnlp.Launcher.launchApplication(Launcher.java:582)
    at net.sourceforge.jnlp.Launcher$TgThread.run(Launcher.java:945)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at net.sourceforge.jnlp.Launcher.launchApplication(Launcher.java:576)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: class "com.topcoder.client.contestant.Coder"'s signer information does not match signer information of other classes in the same package
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.checkCerts(ClassLoader.java:891)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.preDefineClass(ClassLoader.java:661)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:754)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:473)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:74)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:369)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:363)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at net.sourceforge.jnlp.runtime.JNLPClassLoader.access$1701(JNLPClassLoader.java:105)
    at net.sourceforge.jnlp.runtime.JNLPClassLoader$5.run(JNLPClassLoader.java:1748)
    at net.sourceforge.jnlp.runtime.JNLPClassLoader$5.run(JNLPClassLoader.java:1745)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at net.sourceforge.jnlp.runtime.JNLPClassLoader.findClass(JNLPClassLoader.java:1744)
    at net.sourceforge.jnlp.runtime.JNLPClassLoader.loadClassExt(JNLPClassLoader.java:1781)
    at net.sourceforge.jnlp.runtime.JNLPClassLoader.loadClass(JNLPClassLoader.java:1581)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethod(Class.java:2128)
    at java.awt.Component.isCoalesceEventsOverriden(Component.java:6224)
    at java.awt.Component.access$500(Component.java:186)
    at java.awt.Component$3.run(Component.java:6178)
    at java.awt.Component$3.run(Component.java:6176)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.awt.Component.checkCoalescing(Component.java:6175)
    at java.awt.Component.<init>(Component.java:6144)
    at java.awt.Container.<init>(Container.java:285)
    at java.awt.Panel.<init>(Panel.java:64)
    at java.awt.Panel.<init>(Panel.java:56)
    at java.applet.Applet.<init>(Applet.java:65)
    at javax.swing.JApplet.<init>(JApplet.java:131)
    at com.topcoder.client.contestApplet.ContestApplet.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.topcoder.client.contestApplet.runner.generic.main(Unknown Source)
    ... 6 more
```

What does ***java.lang.SecurityException*** mean and how can I resolve it in this case?

Answer (score 1):

**SOLVED THE ISSUE!**

In my case, the jnlp file provided brought the issue.
Instead, I used a topcoder jnlp file suggested in quora. Here is the link [topcoder jnlp](https://community.topcoder.com/contest/arena/ContestAppletProd.jnlp)

An error of this form appeared **Fatal: Application Error: Cannot grant permission to unsigned jars.**Here is a link that can help you counter the problem [unsigned jar solve](https://velenux.wordpress.com/2017/06/07/workaround-for-javaws-jnpl-error-cannot-grant-permissions-to-unsigned-jars/)